# Whats wrong with my jquery select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

login_view.php

I am just trying to use some jQuery to select the a drop down I have created via code igniter's form helper. I have tried different javascript statements on the browser console but keep getting "undefined" for this form element. :(

```
<?php

    //build html for company drop down
    $form_options['--'] = "--";f

    foreach ($client_list as $client) {
        $form_options[$client['co_id']] = $client['co_name'];
    }

    $js = 'id="companies"';
    echo form_dropdown('', $form_options,'', $js);

?>
<input id="login" type="submit" value="Login">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">

$('#login').click(function() {
    var co_id = $(this).find('#companies').val();
    console.log(co_id);     
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case there is not need to use `find()` because the element `companies` doesn't have `#login` as its parent.  So you need to change it too

```
var co_id = $('#companies').val();
```

Comment: This worked, but I still don't understand why it is not appearing in console log, and also if I type in 'co_id' into console log after clicking...

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
var co_id = $('#companies').val();
```

---

`$(this).find('#companies').val();` you are trying to find element with id `companies` inside element with id `login` which doesn't exists .

Id's are unique so can call them directly using id-selector

Comment: This worked, but I still don't understand why it is not appearing in console log, and also if I type in 'co_i.d' into console log after clicking...

Comment: @thetao can you post generated html of form .?